# How to pass JS variables to JSX files

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, pymongo, tornado

I'm using mongo, tornado, and react.

from the tornado server I got my data, I sent it to the html template and then parsed it to JSON, now I want to use this variable "obj" and pass it down to my jsx file, how can I do it?

this is my js code and the script to my react:
[image]

and this my JSX file:
[image]

Comment: use `export default var obj .. // ` and use `import obj from <./filename.js>` in your React component

Comment: Please don't use images for code. Copy and paste the relevant code inside `codeblock` in your question.

Comment: Globals are always available. The "glory" of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `window` global variable (which is accessed from anywhere in your code).

In your tornado template you should use:

```
<script>
    window.obj = JSON.parse(text);
</script>
```

And inside your `jsx` file you can access that variable from the `window` object:

```
render() {
    console.log(window.obj);
}
```